# Gif play slow on certain gif picture

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using Glide library to load gif files into my app. Here what I implemented:

```
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewPreview = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(gifSplach);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://i.imgur.com/Cpw2pk6.gif")
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {


                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    //Toast.makeText(activity, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

            .into(imageViewPreview);
```

But for some reason the gif files are loading with very slow frame. I tried to google but I weren't able to figure it out. I am using Glide Version 3.7.0

Comment: maybe it is because it is downloaded slow? try pre-downloading it and putting it into assets, and playing it from assets

Comment: My .gif memory size is 5 MB and its also slow even i get from assets/raw folder.

Comment: Your `.gif` size is 5.2 MB this could be a reason behind slow frame rate

Comment: ok, are you sure that the gif itself has a quick frame rate?

Comment: Gif file size is not matter, Android OS cache the GIF first then load it.

Comment: ok, I see the gif frame rate is quite fast

Answer (score 0):

*You don't need any library, simply use this code:*
**Step 1**

```
public class GifView extends View {
 public Movie mMovie;
  public long movieStart;
private int gifId;

 public GifView(Context context) {
super(context);
 }

  public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs); 

 initializeView(attrs.getAttributeResourceValue
 ("http://schemas.android.com/apk/r
    es-auto", "src", 0));
 }

   public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);


 initializeView(attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/
  res-auto", "src", 0));
}

 private void initializeView(final int id) {
InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(id);
mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
this.gifId = id;
 }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
   super.onDraw(canvas);
  long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

  if (movieStart == 0) {
    movieStart = now;
  }

if (mMovie != null) {
    int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight() - 
  mMovie.height());
    this.invalidate();
  }
   }

      public void setGIFResource(int resId) {
    this.gifId = resId;
    initializeView(this.gifId);
   }

   public int getGIFResource() {
   return this.gifId;
   }
  }
```

**Step 2: Add following lines in res/attrs.xml**

```
 <declare-styleable name="GIFView">
 <attr name="src" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**Step 3: Add this line your AndroidManifest.xml in specific activity**

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

**Step 4: Create this view in your XML:**

```
<com.thigale.testproject.GifView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
components:src="@drawable/loading" />
```

**Step 5 In the parent activity where you created the view, add the following lines:**

```
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

I reduce the `.gif` size and load it from drawable. It will work for me.

```
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewPreview = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(gifSplach);
Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.gif_splash)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {


                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                //Toast.makeText(activity, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        })
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

        .into(imageViewPreview);
```

Comment: Good brother its frame rates depend on its size